# Using "overflow:hidden;" on a div inside a div

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a set of 6 divs nested in another div. i have a border-radius set for the parent and no border radius on the nested divs. their combined width is exactly the width of the inner area of the parent div. they are all floated left. in this setup, the corners of the children spill over the rounded corners of the parent. setting overflow to hidden seems to do nothing.

Does anyone know how to hide those corners that are overflowing from the parent?

I am using a css reset which is not in the attached code. that particular file is available here: [reset.css](http://79.170.44.85/rasmussenprojects.com/reset.css)

And a link to this page (so you can see what i mean)

79.170.44.85/rasmussenprojects.com/home.html

EDIT: heres a screenshot of what firefox shows in case its not displaying properly for you:

i.stack.imgur.com/OHkng.png

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
        <!--
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
        -->
        <style>
            html, body{
                    background-color:rgb(32,32,32);
                    width:1366px;
                    height:637px;
                    position:relative;
                    }
                #banner_logotext{
                    color:rgb(16,16,16);
                    width:1074px;
                    text-align:center;
                    font-size:32px;
                    font-weight:700;
                    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    }
                #banner_slogantext{
                    color:rgb(16,16,16);
                    width:1074px;
                    text-align:center;
                    font-size:12px;
                    line-height:6px;
                    margin-top:8px;
                }
                .content-panel{
                    background-color:rgb(64,64,64);
                    margin:0 auto;
                    border: 2px solid rgb(16,16,16);
                    border-radius:16px;
                    }
                #banner{
                    width:1074px;
                    height:90px;
                    padding-top:8px;
                    }
                #navbar{
                    width:1074px;
                    height:45px;
                    }
                .navbar-tab{
                    width:178.333333333px;
                    height:41px;
                    float: left;
                    background-color:rgb(48,48,48); 
                    border: 2px solid black;
                }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="content-panel" id="banner">
            <p  id="banner_logotext">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            </p>
            <p  id="banner_slogantext">
                "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum 
                <br></br>quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="content-panel" id="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-tab">

            </div>
            <div class="navbar-tab">

            </div>
            <div class="navbar-tab">

            </div>
            <div class="navbar-tab">

            </div>
            <div class="navbar-tab">

            </div>
            <div class="navbar-tab">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're linked page has a dark overlay that obscures the content you're trying to show us.

Comment: .content-panel { overflow:hidden; }

Comment: @Madbreaks see the edit, a screenshot can be found here: i.stack.imgur.com/OHkng.png

Comment: Setting `overflow:hidden` works just fine for me: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBeKWq

Comment: @JustinBreiland awesome thanks =)...dont know why i didnt think to place that on the parent. if you make it an answer ill accept it (include the fact that it must be used on the parent of the overflowing object, not the child which is overflowing) =)

Comment: I would also add .nav-tab:first-child { border-top-left-radius: 13px; border-bottom-left-radius: 13px;}     .nav-tab:last-child {border-top-right-radius: 13px; border-bottom-right-radius: 13px; }

Comment: your parent div has `class="content-panel" id="navbar"` none of those contain an `overflow:hidden` add it to one of them and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `overflow:hidden` you are telling an element to hide any children that overflow out its bounds. As such, in your scenario, you have to set it for the `#navbar` instead of for each `.navbar-tab`.

```
#navbar{ overflow:hidden; }
```

As was mentioned by Justin Breiland, you can also round some of the corners of the first and last `.navbar-tab`s for better presentation.

```
.navbar-tab:first-child { border-top-left-radius: 13px; border-bottom-left-radius: 13px; }
.navbar-tab:last-child { border-top-right-radius: 13px; border-bottom-right-radius: 13px; }
```

Full example in snippet. Live example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBeKWq

```css
html, body{
  background-color:rgb(32,32,32);
  width:1366px;
  height:637px;
  position:relative;
}
#banner_logotext{
  color:rgb(16,16,16);
  width:1074px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:32px;
  font-weight:700;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#banner_slogantext{
  color:rgb(16,16,16);
  width:1074px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:6px;
  margin-top:8px;
}
.content-panel{
  background-color:rgb(64,64,64);
  margin:0 auto;
  border: 2px solid rgb(16,16,16);
  border-radius:16px;
}
#banner{
  width:1074px;
  height:90px;
  padding-top:8px;
}
#navbar{
  width:1074px;
  height:45px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.navbar-tab{
  width:175px;
  height:41px;
  float: left;
  background-color:rgb(48,48,48); 
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.navbar-tab:first-child{
  border-top-left-radius: 13px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 13px;
}
.navbar-tab:last-child{
  border-top-right-radius: 13px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-panel" id="banner">
  <p  id="banner_logotext">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </p>
  <p  id="banner_slogantext">
    "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum 
    <br></br>quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
</p>
</div>
<div class="content-panel" id="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-tab">

  </div>
  <div class="navbar-tab">

  </div>
  <div class="navbar-tab">

  </div>
  <div class="navbar-tab">

  </div>
  <div class="navbar-tab">

  </div>
  <div class="navbar-tab">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

adiing `overflow:hidden` works on your code

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  width: 1366px;
  height: 637px;
  position: relative;
}
#banner_logotext {
  color: rgb(16, 16, 16);
  width: 1074px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#banner_slogantext {
  color: rgb(16, 16, 16);
  width: 1074px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
.content-panel {
  background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid rgb(16, 16, 16);
  border-radius: 16px;
}
#banner {
  width: 1074px;
  height: 90px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
#navbar {
  width: 1074px;
  height: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar-tab {
  width: 178.333333333px;
  height: 41px;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-panel" id="banner">
  <p id="banner_logotext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <p id="banner_slogantext">"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum
    <br></br>quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."</p>
</div>
<div class="content-panel" id="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-tab"></div>
  <div class="navbar-tab"></div>
  <div class="navbar-tab"></div>
  <div class="navbar-tab"></div>
  <div class="navbar-tab"></div>
  <div class="navbar-tab"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user2944537 There should be a button to insert it when editing your question or answer. It should be the 7th button or so in the top ribbon, called "Code Snippet". You can also use the shortcut Ctrl-M.

Comment: @Marcelo awesome! much appreciated ^.^